# Google sheets countif: condition on the headers of a range

Tags: google-sheets

I have this `countif()` formula that I want to add some additional logic to. I want to make it so that only where values are `YES` within the headers of the range are counted rather than the entire range. So, instead of the result be 6, it should be 3, as B2, C2, and D2 are all the headers of the range that are `YES`. I tried wrapping the `countif()` in an `if()` but couldn't seem to get it to work.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To perform a conditional count with more than one condition, you can use the COUNTIFS function.

```cpp
=COUNTIFS(B2:H2,"x",B1:H1,"YES")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:H1="Yes")*(B2:H2="x"))
```

[image]